# Deprecation warnings when running "npm install --global expo-cli"

Tags: react-native, npm

I get these warnings when running

```
$ npm install --global expo-cli
```

When I check if everything has been installed it has but I'm not sure if the deprecation warnings will cause a problem later.

In an attempt to fix them I have removed the `package-lock.json` file and re-run `npm install`. I've updated to versions on what I can but when I run:

```
$ npm install --global expo-cli
```

it doesn't appear to have fixed any of the deprecation warnings at all. Is any of this a concern, if so any idea how to fix it?

```
npm WARN deprecated topo@2.0.2: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).

npm WARN deprecated @hapi/pinpoint@2.0.0: Moved to 'npm install @sideway/pinpoint'

npm WARN deprecated @hapi/formula@2.0.0: Moved to 'npm install @sideway/formula'

npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated

npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported

npm WARN deprecated hoek@4.2.1: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).

npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated

npm WARN deprecated @hapi/address@4.1.0: Moved to 'npm install @sideway/address'

npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.

npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.

npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142

npm WARN deprecated @hapi/joi@17.1.1: Switch to 'npm install joi'

npm WARN deprecated joi@11.4.0: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).

npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.12: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
```

Comment: Fundamentally, if the packages you rely on have dependencies that are deprecated, there's not much you can do about that. Will it cause problems? Possibly, if any bugs or vulnerabilities are identified in those deprecated packages they won't get fixed.